# .htaccess /public occurs on working on laravel lumen

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, lumen

I have this domain example.com, Whenever user opens that domain `example.com` it redirects to `www.example.com/en`

It is in lumen framework (laravel). There are two .htaccess files. One is at the root of project and one is inside the `/public` folder of project.

In root .htaccess, i'm redirecting it to /public folder, so the project should run. It is working. Whenever i open [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) or example.com it redirects to [www.example.com/en](http://www.example.com/en) which is perfect but when i open inner pages url. For example.

`https://www.example.com/inner-page` it redirects to `www.example.com/en/inner-page` (it works)
`https://example.com/inner-page` it redirects to `www.example.com/en/inner-page` (Not Working)

Here is what I have tried so far.

Root Htaccess contains below code.

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L] </ifModule>`

/public .htaccess contains below code.

`

Options -MultiViews -Indexes

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.example.ae/en [L,R=301]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

`